# Path app native objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

relatively new to iphone dev, but i was interested in the app Path.
its a social network app but its so beautifully created.
is this native objective c?
or does it use a js framework such as a Cappuccino?
the UI feels very much like html5.

thanks,
dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the screenshots, it can definitely be done in Objective-C and Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people have tried to copy the look and feel, and many have created open source projects on github, for example [DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController).

Also, check out [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com/) which is a great reference for iOS open source controls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it is native. The animations and the general responsiveness are way too smooth for a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Very native, and some low level parts to boot.  You could not get performance like that currently out of an HTML 5 UI.

http://www.quora.com/Was-the-2-0-iOS-version-of-Path-written-entirely-in-native-code

There are no shortcuts to greatness.

Comment: wasn't looking for a shortcut, just generally what tools are used to create it.  thanks

Comment: The tools are the same ones everyone else uses, Objective-C and XCode.